# CSS - do not show symbol at anchor with ::before

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have some code in my WP CSS that shows a link-symbol before links on pages and articles. Here is section of the styles for styling anchors:

```
.entry-container .entry-content a::before {
  display: inline-block;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  padding-right: 4px;
  font: var(--fa-font-solid);
  content: "\f0c1"; 
}
```

Problem: The symbol shows before anchors too.
On one page I managed to hide them successfully using this chunk of CSS:

```
#mpm.wpsal-anchor::before {
  display: none;
}
```

This works fine.
But on the other page, I have several anchors and I want to use a css code, that hides all of them without typing each anchor! I tried

```
[class$="wpsal-anchor::before"] {
  display: none !important;
}
```

but without success.
Do anyone have a suggestion or solution?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you not want the symbol to show at all across your site?

Comment: Only not in front of an anchor, all across the site.

Comment: Gotcha I will add an answer you can try

Answer (score 0):

So based on your reply of not wanting the before to show on any anchor element there are a few things you can try

You can use the * in CCS to target all elements and follow it with an anchor. The CSS below says that for all elements that have an anchor tag to not display the before pseudo element. Give that a try. I would put it at the top of your CSS just in case other elements use before. You could also try it without the ( and just use a::before

```
* a::before { display: none; }
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is not working. Only * a::before { display: none !important; } but that removes the element in every link, text too.

Comment: Gotcha so what I would try is using that in conjunction with a > based on the parent. Like whatever is the parent element of wpsal-anchor do this parent > .wpsal-anchor and that will target only the anchors that are direct children of that.